# I can't understand how this code works

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am facing trouble understanding how exactly does the code return a value to randFace();

I have understood the use of rand(0,5), so that it can randomly generate a number which happens to be the length of the ["crown", "anchor",..] array.

I cannot understand the working of the code. Let's say, rand(0,5) returns 3 as a number, then I do get the idea that randFace() would return "spade", but how?

```
function rand(m, n) {
return m + Math.floor((n - m + 1)*Math.random());
}

// randomly returns a string representing one of the six
// Crown and Anchor faces

function randFace() {
return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]
[rand(0, 5)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code, rewritten for easier understanding. Does the same thing. Only extracted two variables and gave them names.

```
function randFace() {
  var faces = ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"];
  var faceIndex = rand(0, 5);
  return faces[faceIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `array[index]`, you will get element at position `index` in that array. If there is not element, `undefined` will be returned as default.

You code is a shorter version of something like this:

```js
function rand(m, n) {
  return m + Math.floor((n - m + 1) * Math.random());
}

function randFace(m,n) {
  var array = ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"];
  var index = rand(m,n);
  return array[index]
}

console.log(randFace(0,5))
console.log(randFace(10,15))
```

So when you do `functionName(args)`, function will be called first and the output will be passed to parent scope. So when you do `[...][rand(0,5)]`, first `rand(0,5)` will execute.

The output will be used as index value to fetch element in array.

As correctly commented by @[sergio tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev), in following line

```
return ["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"][rand(0,5)]
```

order of execution would be

1. initialize array: `["crown", "anchor", "heart", "spade", "club", "diamond"]`
2. Then `rand(0,5)` and output will be passed to second `[]`
3. Second `[]` will be executed and element will be fetched
4. fetched value will be returned.